# IN C, after closed the program again open that program then how to store that intial value

Tags: c, arrays

I made one header file myh.h in which the username and password of particular person is given after withdrawing the money..and closed the program after open again then its shows actual value,not a change value(balance of that person)
myh.h header file ...for ex: username:parthin
Password:parthinb
Pressing 1
after 10 is press balance is 2,now again open then current balance how to change..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<conio.h>
const char *p[]={ "parthinb ", "baraiyab ","purvikbb " };
const char *u[]={"parthin","baraiya","purvik"};
int account(char name[10],int i)
{
    int n,num;
     int b[]={12,34,56};
    printf("Welcome %s\n", name);
    printf("Your current balance is:%d",b[i]);
    printf("\n To Withdraw Money press 1:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    switch(n)
    {
        case 1:
        clrscr();
        printf("Enter the money should to withdraw:");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        printf("\nYour current balance is::%d",b[i]-num);
        b[i]=b[i]-num;
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is main program..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "myh.h"

int main()
{
    char un[20], pass[10], c;
    int i;
start:
    printf("Enter USER NAME::");
    gets(un);
    startp:
    printf("Enter Password of 8 Digitis::");
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        c = getch();
        pass[i]=c;
        c = '*';
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    pass[i] = ' ';
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(un,u[i])==0)
        break;
    }
    if (strcmp(un, u[i]) == 0)
    {
        if (strcmp(pass, p[i]) == 0)
        {
            printf("\nCORRECT\n");
            account(un,i);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nPassword mis-match\n");
            goto startp;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nUSER Name or password doesnot match..\n");
        goto start;
    }
```

}

Comment: Save/read data to/from a file: `FILE *datafile;`, `datafile = fopen("/path/to/accounts.txt", "r");` or `datafile = fopen("/path/to/accounts.txt", "w");`. Don't forget to check for errors and  `fclose(datafile);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as [pmg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25324/pmg) said, you have to store data in a file or database to keep the updated balance after closing the program.

For your main program, its not a good idea to use `goto` statement, it makes your code not good to read. use loop or cut your program into functions.